# Automatically remove all PDF content outside a crop area

Tags: pdf

For a deck of lecture slides, I have extracted several vector illustrations from a PDF-file. I did this by highlighting the relevant area in Preview.app, copying, and opening a new file from the clipboard.

The figures look just fine, even though I noticed that the files are a little large. When I open them in Illustrator, I can see what's described in the screenshot – that all of the page content is still there, it's just hidden because it lies outside the crop area.

[image: These two windows show the same file]

Now I could simply remove everything except the relevant figures in Illustrator, but I would much rather automate the process, since I have a large number of figures.

How can I automate this process such that everything outside the crop area is discarded and everything inside it is preserved as a vector image?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried it with foxit reader(free version)(https://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf-reader/)? crop and take snapshot of the selected area with foxit reader (tools menu>snapshot) and then paste it in the illustrator. This way it will only contain the selected area

Comment: I've been trying with Adobe Acrobat. I would assume that anything called a "snapshot" feature would rasterize, no? At least that's what Acrobat's snapshot feature does.

Comment: No it will not rasterize it. It just takes a picture of the selected area.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does seem to rasterize it. The output is a `png` file; just like with Acrobat's snapshot function...

Answer (score 2):

In Acrobat Pro, go to Preflight and select the setting below.
[image: Preflight setting]

Then click edit to the right
[image: Settings for removal]

You should be able to create Adobe droplets with this preflight setting for automation

Answer (score 1):

You can use redact utility to remove the content.

- Just go to https://doxiview.cib.de/showcase/index.html?locale=default
- Choose redact tool
- upload your PDF
- Choose on the right Select Area and redact fill color as white
- Mark all content, which you want to remove
- click on apply
- download PDF
- Afterwards you can crop the PDF and you won't have the content being still there.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work for me because I have several hundred figures that are cropped already. I want to use the cropped frame as it is already to define what is to be removed and what is to be retained. Also, I suspect that the browser app you recommend simply places a white rectangle over the undesired areas, which does not solve the file size problem...

Comment: I know the pdf library which they use. They make real redaction - no white rectangles over text. So the content is removed.

Comment: Another way could be, that you print the already cropped PDF on a pdf printer. Adobe doesn't print content, which is outside the page dimensions.

Comment: I already thought of that. Unfortunately that outputs the figures on a page of a specified format (A4 by default), so that I would still have to crop the output again.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to rasterize. Just crop the pages then use Acrobat DC to "Sanitize" the document. That will completely remove any non-visible parts of the file.

Comment: This sounds like it is exactly what I'm looking for. Unfortunately, "sanitizing" apparently automatically rasterized all imagery. Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: The Sanitize operation will only rasterize when it absolutely needs to in order to handle some transparency or font cropping issue. It may just be that your PDF was created in a way that Sanitize can't be smart about it.

Comment: If it can't "be smart about it" can I at least tell it _how_ and _where_ to be dumb? As you can see in the screenshot, there are no _visible_ intersections of the figure with the surrounding document. I refuse to believe that this is as much of a challenge as it appears to be; having access to Illustrator and all.

Comment: Can you post the actual PDF somewhere? I can take a look at the content streams for you.